# How to consume ItemService of Sitecore Services Client

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

There are few tabs and a content panel. End user (EU) will click on a tab and the panel's content changes asynchronously.

eg:

```
<ul class="products">
  <li class="p1">product1</li>
  <l1>product2</li>
</ul>
<div class="product-data">
   NAME : <span> <product name here> </span>
   COLOR : <span> <product color here> </span>
</div>

<script>
    (function ($) { 
        $(".p1").click(function(){
            HelloWorld();
        });

        function HelloWorld() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://mysite/Services/myService.asmx/HelloWorld',
                data: "pid:" + someId,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("ERR-" + response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    })(jQuery);    

</script>
```

Each product is an item in the content tree. When EU clicks on a tab, an ajax call is made, which will get that product's data and bind to the panel.

I'm trying to achieve this functionality using a web service and return JSON to front end:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(string pid)
 {
   //get a certain product details and return it as JSON
   Sitecore.Data.Items.Item newItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

   if (newItem != null)
     return newItem.Name;
   else
     return "it was null";                
  }
```

Of course, the result is "it was null" as I understand this has to be done with Item Service of SSC, but unable to find any suitable/beginner example.

Using sitecore 8 with ASP.NET

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve, exactly. What is the problem that you don't know how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use `Entity Service` instead of `Item Service` of `Sitecore.Services.Client`. It will let you serve custom models that are specific to the type of data you want to display for each product.

First, you will need to create a class to represent your Product. It needs to implement `Sitecore.Services.Core.Model.EntityIdentity`.

Just an FYI if you are using Sitecore SPEAK ensure you define a property named `itemId` with that casing, SPEAK requires it.

```
public class ProductModel : Sitecore.Services.Core.Model.EntityIdentity
{
    public string itemId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When Developing with `Sitecore.Services.Client` you'll want to follow Sitecore best practices. A simple `Controller` passing off all the computation to a `Repository` for the type of Model. In this case a ProductRepository.

The controller needs to implement `EntityService` with the type of `Model`.

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ServicesController]
public class ProductController : EntityService<ProductModel>
{
    public ProductController(IRepository<ProductModel> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }

    public ProductController()
        : this(new SitecoreItemRepository())
    {
    }
}
```

This controller exposes the methods of the `Repository` Get, GetById, Add, etc.

```
public class ProductRepository : Sitecore.Services.Core.IRepository<ProductModel>
{
    public ProductModel FindById(string id)
    {
        // code to find by id
    }
}
```

See here for a [full example of Entity Service](https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/02/12/sitecore-hackathon-2015-part-ii-entityservice-in-sitecore-services-client/) and [here](https://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/01/06/entityservice-sitecore-service-client/)

Comment: (1)I should call `ProductRepository.FindById` in my Webservice. Is that right. (2) Where should I create the controller in my solution. (3) Will it be Web API2 controller ?

Comment: 1) The controller will serve that method to web requests e.g. <url>/Product/findById 2) Up to you, a folder for controllers in your web app project typically 3) Just create an empty controller

Comment: There is no `Sitecore.Services.Core` in my solution. I tried adding these dlls, but no luck - Sitecore.Services.Client, Sitecore.Services.Core, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore